# react native tab navigator toggle button snipples?

Tags: react-native, expo

i have a react native tab navigator component created using createBottomTabNavigator, see screenshot.
I tried to do the last icon as a toggle button (with press you toggle
it's state) but not to do any application routing (not to change the active
screen).
Is this possible and or how? thanks

[image: tab screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a lot of trying & reading, but in case anybody needs this, I created a solution.
This reuses the navigation params and a not really well documented tabBarOnPress method (was recently added as PR to the react navigation code).
"geo" is the toggle flag used to highlight the tab button and store information.

`Geo: {
      screen: BarcodeScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarOnPress: ({ scene, jumpToIndex }) => { 
          navigation.setParams({ geo: !navigation.getParam("geo", false)});
        },
       }})}`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small example .

**Here I customized the icon and lable style on the tab selected and un selected**

=> Here is the code inside `tabBarIcon`

```
else if (routeName === 'Scan') {
              iconName = focused ? "ACTIVE_ICON" : "ACTIVE_ICON"
        }
```

When `scan`tabe focused it will check if its is focused or not So here I set ACTIVE ICON ither it is focused or not

=> Same thing i did in `tabbarLael`

```
  if (focused || routeName === "Scan") {
        color = YOUR_ACTIVE_COLOR
    }
```

By comparing screen name set ACTIVE COLOR even though the `scan`  tab is not selected

**FULL CODE**

```
 navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            let iconName;

            if (routeName === 'Lists') {
                iconName = focused ? "ACTIVE_ICON" : "IN_ACTIVE_ICON"
            } else if (routeName === 'Setup') {
                  iconName = focused ? "ACTIVE_ICON" : "IN_ACTIVE_ICON"
            } else if (routeName === 'Scan') {
                  iconName = focused ? "ACTIVE_ICON" : "ACTIVE_ICON"
            } 
            return <Image style={{
                height: 30,
                width: 30
            }}
                source={{
                    uri: iconName
                }}
                resizeMode="center"
            />
        },
        tabBarLabel: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            let color = YOUR_INACTIVE_COLOR;

            let lable;

            if (routeName === 'Lists') {
                lable = "Lists"
            } else if (routeName === 'Setup') {
                lable = "Setup"
            } else if (routeName === 'Scan') {
                lable = "Scan"
            }

           if (focused || routeName === "Scan") {
                color = YOUR_ACTIVE_COLOR
            }





            return <Text style={{
                       fontSize: 9, 
                       textAlign: 'center', 
                       color: color }}>
                     {lable}
                   </Text> },
    }),
```

Comment: thanks, this solves the styling based on a state, however, there is still the problem that the tab does not function as a routing element, I simply have no screen to assign it, it's purpose is to toggle the state only.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your point will you explain by showing gif or explaining deeply

Comment: ok. The tab navigator uses tabs to change the route to navigate screens.however, I need one of the tabs not to change screen, not to change the route, but simply act as a toggle button - switch a flag On/Off. 
Think of it as a checkbox. But it's located in the tab navigator and looks like any other of the tabs.